# Does it say anywhere that the people buried in Kavers don’t like when people put rocks on their kaver

Tags: halacha, torah-study, funeral-burial-levaya, derech-eretz-manners, mishpatim

BH

Does it say anywhere in Torah that the people buried in kavers don’t like it when people put rocks on top of their kevers(like little pebbles like the neshama doesn’t like it)?

Comment: קברי ישראל.  אפי' על קבר אחד יברך הרדב"ז. אבל בהלק"ט ח"א סי' רי"ב חולק וכ' דעל קבר אחד אינו מברך ע"ש. כ' בדרשות מהר"ש כשהיה הולך על הקבר היה אומר יהי רצון שתהא מנוחתו של פלוני פה בכבוד וזכותו יעמוד לי. עוד כתב מה שתולשין עשב או צרור ומשימין על מצבה אינו אלא משום כבוד המת להראות שהוא היה על קברו וכ' בר"מ שיניח ידו על הקבר ע"ש:

https://www.sefaria.org/Ba'er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.224.8

Comment: Why do you think such a text exists?

Comment: Are you suggesting the someone can only be buried using soil that was sifted to remove rocks? Any burial will naturally entail rocks atop the site of burial... what's one more?